# Exporting .jar to use in Unity with 3rd-party libs included: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, unity-game-engine, adt

This seems to be a common issue when exporting jars with Eclipse. Now, my context.

I'm attempting to write Java plugins to use in Unity applications. When I did a simple plugin with no external libraries (except the classes.jar so I can call a UnityPlayerActivity), it worked pretty well. "Now, let's use some utils libraries". So I wrote a plugin which uses Jackson libraries to parse and process JSON data, so I can serialize it to a Java object, or just pass RAW data, then build a Unity (C#) object.

I add the libraries directly from the file system to the 'libs' folder (copying the .jars, not linking them), add to build path, check every one in the **Order and Export**, clean and build, and export to JAR file (not runnable, but simple JAR file). Then, I add my new .jar to Unity Assets/Plugins/Android folder, then build my .apk. As soon as the game starts, I get the classic NoClassDefFoundError because of a constructer using a Jackson class. Checking the .jar contents, I find that Jackson libraries are, indeed, exported and within the 'libs' folder, but still it won't "find" it. The error will be thrown by the main thread, thus the application will crash.

I'm using ADT with API 17, so the libs folder must be named 'libs' (even Eclipse does create this folder when creating a new Android project), JRE 1.6 and Jackson libraries ver. 2.2.0. Already followed a lot of questions here, but none of their suggestions has worked for me.

Any pointers here? Has the Android API version anything to do here? Is there something I'm not doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite new to Java, but as far as I can tell when you use an external JAR file it is dynamically linked. In other words, it stays independent - it is not merged into your library.

This was obvious in my case: The external library I used was Google Analytics. Its JAR file, libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar, is 126 KB. After I added it to my libs directory and built my library I got an output JAR file of only 2 KB...

My solution was to copy the external library JAR file to Assets/Plugins/Android, together with the JAR file I created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my late response.
I sort of did the same thing you are suggesting.